# How to change CD ROM Letter?

Tags: powershell, cd-rom

I want to change letter from D to Z:

```
Set-WmiInstance -InputObject ( Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'd:'" ) -Arguments @{DriveLetter='Z:'}
```

**Error:**

```
Set-WmiInstance : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is
null.
At line:1 char:30
+ Set-WmiInstance -InputObject ( Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter "DriveL ...
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-WmiInstance], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetWmiInstance
```

Comment: Apparently `Get-WmiObject` doesn't return a result. You need to investigate why that is.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers can you please help in this.

Comment: On that system do you have a D: drive? What is the output of only `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'd:'"`

Comment: How would you expect me to do that? I'm not sitting in front of your computer. What output does `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'd:'"` produce if you run it by itself? What output does `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | select DriveLetter` produce?

Answer (score 4):

That error occurs because the WMI query doesn't return anything (probably because there's no device mounted at `D:`).

To avoid it, use the pipeline instead:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'd:'" |Set-WmiInstance -Arguments @{DriveLetter='Z:'}
```

If `Get-WmiObject` doesn't return anything then `Set-WmiInstance` won't run and you won't have any errors

Comment: This will check if exisint cd rom letter is D what is dynamically checking watever the exisitn letter may be change it to z:    @mathia

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the nested `Get-WmiObject` call doesn't return a result. There could be a number of reasons for this:

- system doesn't have an optical drive
- system has an optical drive, but with a different drive letter
- an error occurred (but you set the error action to `SilentlyContinue`)
- …

Generally a better approach is to not rely on the drive letter, but the [drive type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515(v=vs.85).aspx), and -as Mathias pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39964751/1630171)- use a pipeline instead of nesting the command (so that empty results are skipped over instead of throwing an error).

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter 'DriveType=5' |
  Select-Object -First 1 |
  Set-WmiInstance -Arguments @{DriveLetter='Z:'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for CD-ROM Update Powershell codes,

```
# Set CD/DVD Drive to A:
$cd = $NULL
$cd = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_CDROMDrive -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -ErrorAction Stop
if ($cd.Drive -eq "D:")
{
   Write-Output "Changing CD Drive letter from D: to A:"
   Set-WmiInstance -InputObject ( Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'd:'" ) -Arguments @{DriveLetter='a:'}
}
```